# How can storing a bit of information require less mass than an electron?

Tags: information

The prefixes ronna-, ronto-, quetta- and quecto- were adopted recently to mean $10^{27}, 10^{-27}, 10^{30}$ and $10^{-30}.$ According to [The Guardian,](https://www.theguardian.com/science/2022/nov/18/earth-six-ronnagrams-new-prefixes-big-and-small) "An electron weighs about a rontogram, and a single bit of data stored on a mobile phone adds about 10 quectograms to its mass." This means that something with the mass of an electron can store 100 bits. How is this possible? (I think it might have something to do with photons, but they are massless...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's stored in the energy of an electrostatic field, which has mass. It's closely related to photon mass, but not exactly the same. Whether a photon has mass or not depends on just how you define/measure it. A resonant cavity holding a photon has more mass than one without a photon in it.

Comment: But doesn't the mass come from the battery, and isn't more mass radiated as all the things phones radiate: screen light, microwaves, heat, sound....?

Comment: @JEB Sure, all exchanges of energy between the phone and its environment change its mass. Internal transfers of energy don't change the phone's mass, but they may change where the mass is.